# How do I do a deterministic build locally (ContinuousIntegrationBuild flag)?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package, roslyn, .net-standard

When I attempt to publish my package using NuGet Package Explorer, I see the following warning:

[image: Non-Deterministic]

> Deterministic (dll/exe): Non deterministic
> Ensure that the following property is enabled for CI builds
> and you're using at least the 2.1.300 SDK:
>
> ```
> <ContinuousIntegrationBuild>true</ContinuousIntegrationBuild>
> ```

However, when I add that property to the `PropertyGroup` (as described [here](https://github.com/clairernovotny/DeterministicBuilds)), VS 2019 freaks out so badly I literally need to ctrl+alt+delete to close it.

According to [this page](https://gist.github.com/aelij/b20271f4bd0ab1298e49068b388b54ae) the property name is `<Deterministic>`, but that doesn't seem to do anything at all.

So **how do I get deterministic builds to work?**

Visual Studio 2019, v16.7.1
.Net SDK 3.1.401 (LTS)

Comment: Can you post some of the errors you are seeing? As it stands this question is not answerable. The deterministic option you refer to is about the compiler being deterministic (official docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/deterministic-compiler-option)). This flag is on by default in any .NET Core project and therefore specifying it in your project file will do nothing.

Comment: @JonathonMarolf: I already posted the errors I'm seeing. When you enable the flag on local builds, Visual Studio freezes on build and needs to be force-closed.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft The default .csproj generated by VS v16.7.1 for a C# console app has `<Deterministic>true</Deterministic>` under the top `<PropertyGroup>`, and it builds fine locally. So I guess there must be some other difference in your project files.

Comment: what happens when you build from the commandline? I believe Clair's properties will only work in an sdk-style project (the kind generated for a .NET Core project).

Comment: what the `ContinuousIntegrationBuild` actually does when set?

Answer (score 12):

An easier answer is to not mess with `.csproj` files (urgh!) and do this via the command line, in your CI script.

add the `/p:ContinuousIntegrationBuild=true` argument to the `dotnet pack` command.

```
dotnet pack 
    -c $env:CONFIGURATION 
    /p:ContinuousIntegrationBuild=true 
    -p:PackageVersion=$env:APPVEYOR_BUILD_VERSION
```

*(make this all one line. I've multi-lined it, for readability)*

NOTE: the `--no-build` argument is NOT here. We need to build this *again*. Or you add that param to the build step, before this.

This is [taken from an example CI file I use](https://github.com/PureKrome/SimpleHosting/blob/main/appveyor.yml#L59). So when I'm in `release` mode, I pack the library into a nuget and publish it.

Keeps things clean and out of your `.csproj` file (which is very hard to grok and maintain).

Comment: This did it for me. Thanks @Pure.Krome

Comment: How does this issue you raised affect this answer is it still valid?: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/16325

Answer (score 7):

I basically just found the answer in this [blogpost](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/producing-packages-with-source-link/):

> While deterministic builds are enabled by default in .NET SDK projects, there is an extra property, ContinuousIntegrationBuild, to set on the build server to normalize stored file paths. These should not be enabled during local dev or the debugger won’t be able to find the local source files.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TF_BUILD)' == 'true'">
  <ContinuousIntegrationBuild>true</ContinuousIntegrationBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Setting this variable made no difference to me: I'm still getting that same warning when looking at the package using NuGet Package Explorer. Tried both setting it to `true` always (as a test) as well as compiling from cmdline using a custom variable like `TF_BUILD`.

Comment: For me using ContinuousIntegrationBuild is also not working

Comment: I had to enable sourcelink by including the proper package for my source control and then I got all green checkmarks in nuget package explorer

Comment: I had to delete my `obj` folder to get the switch to work. Apparently msbuild clean only deletes some specific things but leaves a bunch of other stuff around: [link](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/12304), so changing the build configuration wasn't fully going through as it reused some old obj files. Once I deleted bin/obj the `ContinuousIntegrationBuild` produces "Deterministic: Valid" in NuGet Package Explorer for me.